# How to avoid OutOfMemoryError uploading file?

Tags: java, resin

I'm trying to upload image files. When uploading files of sizes of about 40 to 200kb everything is fine. But when I try to upload a file of size 459kb sometimes it gets uploaded and sometimes OutOfMemoryError is shown. I don't think that file size is very large for this error to be thrown. I'm using resin. Is it possible there's a resin setting that prevents uploading of large sized files? Because in the code there is nowhere I'm setting any maximum size for file uploading.

Any one have any ideas how to avoid this. I want users to upload images of any size of up to about 10 MB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running out of memory, the first thing to check is how much memory your JVM has allocated. You don't say how Resin is running or which JVM it is using or the OS / host but typically a JVM will be governed by a default heap size and a a maximum heap size. From the command line the standard JVM has `-Xms` and `-Xmx` parameters that govern these values. When the JVM starts it allocates the default heap and it will allow it to grow to the maximum. When an allocation exceeds the maximum heap it might try to release any soft / weak references and other disposable resources, force a GC, but if it still hasn't enough space it will throw an `OutOfMemoryException`. Therefore changing the values can affect when this happens.

The second thing to look for is how you allocate memory in the server. For example, if your server holds a pile of stuff in memory with strong references you can run out of memory, if so consider using a weak references instead or something like [Ehcache](http://ehcache.org/) to move stuff out to disk. Or if your servlet were allocating MB instead of KB due to some kind of calculation error. You shouldn't be trying to read the entire input into memory anyway. Assuming you are implementing a servlet, then the supplied `ServletRequest` / `HttpServletRequest` allows you to access the input stream of the POSTDATA and you can read it in chunks (e.g. 32KB at a time) and write it out to an output buffer in chunks. As a general rule of thumb reading input data in discrete chunks would be better practice anyway since you don't want untrusted data to be able to break your server by passing some massive file to you.

Comment: Thanks. Can you tell me where can I set this -Xms parameter in resin. I'm using jvm 1.5. Also Is there a way where I could upload the file without increasing the heap space. i'm already reading the file using inputstream.(I'm using struts and using FormFile from struts)

Comment: That depends on how you start it, but Caucho have some tuning information which may help. In resin 4.0, there is a resin.xml where you can specify the JVM args - http://caucho.com/resin-4.0/admin/starting-resin-command-line.xtp

Answer (score 1):

[OutOfMemoryError](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html) are thrown by the JVM when not enough memory is available for a particular action (object's instantiation for example)

To avoid such errors you can increase the memory avaible for the JVM at startup time using a specific option depending on your JVM (usually -Xmx512m for 512 megas)

In your case, such small upload should not generate any OutOfMemoryError and I recommend using a tool such as [Memory Analyzer](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) to identify the origin of the error.

Answer (score 0):

While  trying to launch the application set the max and min size for heap and reserved areas

using Xmx Xms Xss

Answer (score 0):

I'll post this because it helped me, I tried fiddling with Tomcat memory allocations (I was running coldfusion and Lucee) but in the end I got around this problem by reading the file from disk instead of from a cfimage (memory):
Excerpt from SQL statement from Disk (worked):

```
<cfqueryparam value="#fileRead("#absFilePath#")#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_blob">,
```

Excerpt from SQL statement from memory (failed with larger files):

```
#Load into cfimage
<cfimage action="read" source="#absFilePath#" name="myImage">
#Try to us it in cfqueryparam example:
<cfqueryparam value="#ImageGetBlob(myImage)#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_blob">,
```

What I find SUPER odd is that I still do read the larger images into a cfimage so I can make a thumbnail, and that's fine, but I have to do the first insert with just a toBinary("Placeholder") and I can set the thumbnail, but then I have to do an update query to replace the "Placeholder" with the fileRead. Odd, but I've tested up to 2MB now and it's fine, whereas before it was failing at ~400KB.